3x3 nodal analysis. I know v2 but I don't know how I can use v2 to find v1 and v3

I tried KCL but I don't know what to do from there. I hope someone can show me how to do it.

This is how I figured out v2 is 12 V.

what's the voltage difference between V2 and V3  (think about how you found V2)

Gabriel, The title says you know $v_2$. So what is it? And how do you know?

The simplest but unfortunately most laborious way is to apply the principle of superposition of effects.

using superposition of effects, wouldn't that defy what the question is asking me to do, if it was to simply find v1,v2 and v3 then i would do it that way, but its asking me to use nodal analysis.

v2 is 12v by analyzing the circuit its like a given

What's the voltage difference between v2 and v1?

@GABRIEL The 12 V voltage supply is given. But $v_2$ is not a given. It is determined by looking at the schematic and the point of reference on the schematic. Once you know $v_2$ then you can look at the other two voltage supplies, with reference to $v_2$, to determine the other nodes. Question: Do you need to apply KCL to this circuit? Are you allowed to just use logic? Or must you set up the math equations and solve them via KCL and simultaneous solutions?

@GABRIEL Let's get something very obvious out of the way: solved as fast as I could type. I guess there's nothing left to do. So were you expected to use KCL on this problem? You brought it up. Is that an issue? Or is it only that you didn't understand the idea of voltage difference? If you need to use KCL, then things are slightly more interesting. If not, then you have the voltages and instead need to work harder at this or else find a better teacher.

my teacher specifically wants me to use nodal analysis to find v1,v2 and v3, otherwise i would use about anything else

V2 is not a given, it's trivial, but not a given.I am not convinced that solving this in the most obvious way is not performing nodal analysis. it seems to me that when you add 12V to 0V to get V2  you are performing nodal analysis.

if the illustration is from a text book, identifying the text book may assist in interpreting the words used in the question.
